# Wordpress - Woocommerce wp_insert_post() 'post_category'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm trying to import woocommerce products with `wp_insert_post()` function but i have problem with `'post_category'`. My code is

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_content'   => $description, 
  'post_name'      =>  $product_name, 
  'post_title'     =>  $product_name, 
  'post_status'    => 'publish', 
  'post_type'      => 'product', 
  'post_author'    => 1, 
  'post_category'  =>  array(9,10)// ids from woocommerce categories
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

But categories are empty. I tried `'product_cat'  =>  array(9,10)` but nothing again. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 9, 'product_cat', true);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 10, 'product_cat', true);
```

Also ensure that terms with id 9 & 10 already exist in `product_cat` taxonomy before importing the product.

Answer (score 1):

You should use slug instead id:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, get_term(9)->slug, 'product_cat', true);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, get_term(16)->slug, 'product_cat', true);
```

If you put here new category slug, WordPress will create it, and attached product to this category.